# Running total mysql query - almost working

Tags: mysql

I am close to accomplishing a running total column but I think I am missing something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SET @runtot := 0;
SELECT
  COUNT(adjustment_id) AS Adjustments,
  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(shifts.outtime)) AS 'Month',
  (@runtot := @runtot + COUNT(adjustment_id)) AS RT
FROM adjustments
  INNER JOIN shifts
    ON (shifts.shiftID = adjustments.shiftID)
  INNER JOIN employees
    ON (shifts.idnum = employees.idnum)
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(shifts.outtime)) = '2012'
GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(shifts.outtime))
ORDER BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(shifts.outtime))ASC
```

The code above outputs:

```
Adjustments | Month      | RT
34          | 2012-08-29 | 34
161         | 2012-09-01 | 161
```

The RT matches the Adjustments and doesn't show the running total as I had hoped.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do your running total over the result of the aggregating query:

```
SET @runtot := 0;

SELECT 
    Adjustments,
    Month,
    (@runtot := @runtot + Adjustments) AS RT
FROM ( SELECT
COUNT(adjustment_id) AS Adjustments,
DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(shifts.outtime)) AS 'Month'
FROM
adjustments
INNER JOIN shifts ON (
shifts.shiftID = adjustments.shiftID
)
INNER JOIN employees ON (shifts.idnum = employees.idnum)
WHERE
YEAR (FROM_UNIXTIME(shifts.outtime)) = '2012'
GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(shifts.outtime))
ORDER BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(shifts.outtime)) ASC
) x
```

Comment: This worked like a champ! (Note I did have to remove the ',' after AS 'Month' cause it caused an error).  You rock Bohemian.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: No worries, and welcome to stackoverflow :) Do come back and join in the community by answering some questions and asking good ones - you'll be surprised what you learn by doing so. (ps I've edited the answer to remove the dangling comma removed)